# Restart Docker Container (Automatically) when Image changes in Portainer(?)

Tags: image, docker, containers, restart, portainer

I have a java WAR file that is of an Image (Docker) and is being started inside a Tomcat (Docker) container. Since the coding changes, the WAR will change also. I would like to do the following:

1. Change the java code Update to Git
2. Have a WAR file created (from code just pushed to Git)
3. create a NEW IMAGE (Docker) that uses the NEW WAR file
4. stop all old containers (running old image)
5. re-start the containers (which will be using the new image)

I am also using Portainer. Is there some series of commands that I can execute / run so that Item #4 and Item #5 can be ran automatically (without requiring human intervention)? Is there some kind of way that this can be done at all?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

[docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) can be helpful for this. You can create a yml file for your application and use docker compose cli to spin up new containers as required. For example I have tomcat/mongo based application with following yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    network_mode: host
  tomcat:
    build: 
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: DockerfileTomcat
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
     - mongodb
```

With folder layout as:

```
├── docker-compose.yml
└── app
    ├── DockerfileTomcat
    └── app.war
```

Where `DockerfileTomcat` takes care of copying the war file in tomcat container as:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5-jre8

RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*

COPY app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
```

In order to start your application you need to run following command in the directory containing `docker-compose.yml`:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Just copy the new war file over app.war each time and run the command above. It will create the base image and launch the updated container.

If this isn't something you are looking for you can write a BASH script to automate the process. Let me know if you want me to post it here.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Will this work with Portainer as well? (I kinda like being able to see the containers running through a UI).

Comment: docker compose with portainer isn't supported yet but I do see [work](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/257) being done on it. See portainer [roadmap](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/projects/2#card-523997) for details.

Comment: Thanks much for the input! I will be waiting for the new feature :-) In the meantime, do you think it would be possible to duplicate such functionality with a cron job perhaps?

Comment: @Casey we're currently working on adding the ability to 'restart a container with the latest image', this should be available soon !